# Is it possible to allow the user to select the "Color Saturation" Value In the Shape map preview feature?

Tags: microsoft-powerbi

I've been looking to produce a dashboard for my company using the shape map preview feature to spatially visualise data such as sales, hours of work spent on projects and so on. I've added slicers to allow the user to look at data for specific people, within a particular date range. Now what i'd like to do is allow the user to specify which column of data the map is displaying.

This is determined by the "Color saturation" data field in the shape map visual, is there any way to allow this field to be controlled by a slicer?

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

I would tackle this using the "disconnected slicer" design pattern. Essentially you construct a reference table to list the fields (e.g. using Enter Data, presented as a Slicer), along with a Measure to switch the result based on the selection.

The usual Measure pattern is something like:

```
My Dynamic Measure = SWITCH ( SELECTEDVALUE ( 'My Fields'[Field] , "ZZZ) , "Field A" , SUM ( 'My Actual Data'[Field A] ) , "Field B" , SUM ( 'My Actual Data'[Field B] ) )
```